# Get plain text from Everything HTTP server

Tags: everything

I'm trying to get plain text from Voidtools Everything HTTP server (https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/http/) but I cannot find an option to do this.
My use case for this is to generate a listfile to be used as input for 7zip. I know I can use Everything command line tool `ES.EXE` but I need the advanced filters, eg:

```
wget http://localhost:8010?s="q*.jpg dm:gt:2010"^&json=1^&path_column=1 -O lst
```

and this filters aren't supported in `ES.EXE` as far I can tell. I could reprocess the json in Python but the output can be millions of pathnames so I would prefer to get the plain listfile if possible.
Until now I've been using `hddb` https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/hddb.html to do this but it seems to have problems with some unicode characters generating the listfile

Comment: @AndrewMorton: then I get HTML :) Worst, HTMLsplit by pages